# onclick and ontouchstart don't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, onclick, ontouch

I am trying to add a click event to this img tag. It works fine on desktop and sometimes on ipad. But it never works on mobile. 
I have tried `

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-center" ontouchstart="addImagesToArray()"/>
```

and

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-center" onclick="addImagesToArray()"/>
```

Just to test on mobile. But no one seems to work. 
This is what my js looks like

```
function addImagesToArray(){
      alert("clicked!");
}
```

I do not know why this isn't working because I don't even see an error in the console. I'm really lost here. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Working fine for me...

Comment: Its working..have you run only with simple code on your mobilel. or include with your full javascript?

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. It was a problem with the way my images were laid out. onclick and ontouchstart work on across all mobile devices.